# Open Gmail Add-on by default on opening mail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I am working on Gmail Add-on using Google Apps Script.

I wanted to know if there is any way in which my Add-on will be opened by default without clicking on the add-on icon? For example, if the mail contains an attachment, add-on should open without clicking the icon on the sidebar on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, there is no way we can achieve that and that is not possible also because if multiple add ons have similar behaviour on opening mail with attachments, which add on should open. Many race conditions come, so I guess it is not good to have such a feature.